# Reading a csv file with batch to create users

Tags: loops, csv, batch-file, windows-server-2008

I'm an IT student. I was trying to make users in my virtual machine of windows server 2008, i though that should be a better way to make them less than make it one by one, then i found that i can make users with a database, in that case csv, and a loop script. But cause my low level of knowledge about commands and batch files i can't achieve my goal. This is what i have in the csv file:

```
Pedro,12345,939293c
Juanjo,23456,213123v
Eufrasio,34567,2131312b
Dani,45678,123213n
Pepe,56789,12344v
Manolo,67891,12312567b
```

And this is the batch I've made, I'm stuck in the part of the echo, the command didn't read

```
SET LOCAL
@echo incio del script
set n1=
set n2=
set n3=

for /F "tokens=1,2,3* delims=," %%i in (Libro2.csv) do (
    set "n1=%%i"
    set "n2=%%j"
    set "n3=%%k"
    echo %n1 %n2 %n3
)

pause
```

Comment: In a console window, enter `net help user`.  That should help you figure out what to do with `%%i`, `%%j`, and `%%k`.  The `%n1` `%n2` and `%n3` variables won't work without delayed expansion within a `for` loop (not that `%n1` is acceptable anyway,  Batch variables are retrieved as `%n1%`, etc).  But you really don't need to reassign `%%i` `%%j` and `%%k` to new variables anyway.  Just use them as they are.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in batch are referenced with `%var%`, not `%var`.

But in blocks (between `(` and `)` you need to enable delayed expansion to show the current value (if you change them inside the block):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set x=one
if 1==1 (
  set x=two
  echo %x% !x!
)
```

change your script a little bit:

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
@echo incio del script
set n1=
set n2=
set n3=

for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%i in (Libro2.csv) do (
    set "n1=%%i"
    set "n2=%%j"
    set "n3=%%k"
    echo %%i %%j %%k
    echo !n1! !%n2! !%n3!
)
```

(Note: you can directly work with the `for`-variables - see the first echo in the block)

(Note: `tokens=1,2,3,*` means: for the fourth token take the rest of the line. You don't really need it here, as you don't use `%%l`)